# Extracting ontology namespaces/prefixes with OWL API

Tags: java, namespaces, ontology, prefix, owl-api

Within a `.owl` file, I'm declaring some prefixes like this:

```
Prefix(:=<http://default.ont/my_ont/>)
Prefix(ex:=<http://example.org/ex#>)
Prefix(ex2:=<http://example2.org/ex#>)
...
```

And using my ontology in a Java project like this:

```
OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
OWLOntology ontology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(new File(resourceFullPath(ontologyFilename)));
```

Now I want to build a `Map<String, String>` in a programmatic way with the following content:

```
{
  ""    -> "http://default.ont/my_ont/",
  "ex"  -> "http://example.org/ex#",
  "ex2" -> "http://example2.org/ex#"
}
```

How can I do this with [OWL API](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi) (i.e. without parsing the `.owl` file by myself)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The prefixes found during parsing are held as part of the `OWLDocumentFormat` instance associated to the ontology:

```
OWLDocumentFormat format = manager.getOntologyFormat(ontology);
if (format.isPrefixOWLDocumentFormat()) {
    // this is the map you need
    Map<String, String> map = format.asPrefixOWLDocumentFormat().getPrefixName2PrefixMap();
}
```